# JavaScript opening file automatically after download

Tags: javascript, android, download

I'm completly unfamiliar with JavaScript but I'm performing a test of Android security vulnerability described [here](http://thomascannon.net/blog/2010/11/android-data-stealing-vulnerability/).

I'm looking for JavaScript code which would open a HTML file when it completes downloading. I tried to find it, but I get mismatched results of JavaScript for downloading files.

I would appreciate some code or hint where to find it.

Comment: Testing or hacking script?

Comment: It's for my academic research of android security. I just check some attacks to prove it's possible. However I never used javascript before.

Comment: I would guess that the security issue has to due with using WebViews which allows you to use javascript controlled via a local application. The local application would have SD card access and also Web access.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I need that javascript scanning local environment of SD card. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

So here is how it is done:

You redirect to the the html file which is served with content headers causing the browser to download it as an html file instead of rendering it. You then cause the browser to redirect to the file which has been downloaded to the SD card.

The redirects are done by using `setTimeout()` in JavaScript.

The full source of the Metasploit module for this vulnerability can be found here for your testing:

https://dev.metasploit.com/redmine/projects/framework/repository/entry/modules/auxiliary/gather/android_htmlfileprovider.rb

Comment: Thank you for your hints but I still cannot have that downloaded html file opened.

Comment: I have serving *.php file which forces download o f HTML file. I embed a javascript setTimeout() method in this PHP file to auto-open HTML file but this doesn't work. I try with the complete path and name, but it still doesn't work.